# MySQL Looking for multiple IDs

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a News Feed and I'm stuck. 
Let's say I have this MySQL table with some data called table `friends`:

and let's say I have this for statuses called table `status`

And for example, my user id corrolates with `friend_1` or `friend_2` on `friends` and `uid` for `status`. What MySQL query would I need to use to be able to see which friends I have from `friends` that have rows of data in `status`?

Comment: pseudo-y: SELECT * FROM Friends WHERE id IN status.uid

Comment: I'm a bit confused on your model.  Where does user ID fit in I don't see it on any of the tables. is it the ID on "Friends?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT status.*
FROM status, friends
WHERE (friend_2 = uid AND friend_1 = <your_id>) 
OR (friend_1 = uid AND friend_2 = <your_id>);
```

In case on eevery friendship insert 2 rows ( and ) - you don't need the `OR (...)`

Answer (score 1):

This will select all statuses for friends of current user.

```
SELECT s.*
FROM status s
INNER JOIN friends f ON f.friend_2 = s.uid
WHERE f.friend_1 = your_current_user;
```

Also I recommend not to treat friendship links bidirectional. Make separate links. For example, if users 1 and 5 are friends, you'll have two records.

```
| friend_1 | friend_2 |
|    1     |    5     |
|    5     |    1     |
```

This increases storage space, but simplifies queries. Also it enables one sided friendship, should you need it. :-)